# python subprocess.check_output() json parameter parsing in ubuntu container

Tags: python, subprocess

Trying to execute code with subprocess.check_output() inside an ubuntu 20.04 container:

```
try:
    out = subprocess.check_output(exe)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    log.error(f"unable to execute:{' '.join(exe)} -> {e} -> {out}")
    return None
```

```
0211022170027|INFO|command used: ./bin/elkq.py --env=test --vertical=trk --index='bps-trace-*'
 --testenv=test12 --fields=@timestamp,message,bps.application --aggs=bps.application --start=now-4h
 --end=now --json --fany='("error")' --fmust='[{"fields.buypass.com/name": "id-pro-_VERT_-*"},
 {"bps.application": "*-_TESTENV_"}]'
20211022170028|ERROR|unable to execute:./bin/elkq.py --env=test --vertical=trk --index='bps-trace-*'
 --testenv=test12 --fields=@timestamp,message,bps.application --aggs=bps.application --start=now-4h
 --end=now --json --fany='("error")' --fmust='[{"fields.buypass.com/name": "id-pro-_VERT_-*"},
 {"bps.application": "*-_TESTENV_"}]' ->
 Command '['./bin/elkq.py', '--env=test', '--vertical=trk', "--index='bps-trace-*'",
 '--testenv=test12', '--fields=@timestamp,message,bps.application', '--aggs=bps.application',
 '--start=now-4h', '--end=now', '--json', '--fany=\'("error")\'',
 '--fmust=\'[{"fields.buypass.com/name": "id-pro-_VERT_-*"}, {"bps.application": "*-_TESTENV_"}]\'']'
 returned non-zero exit status 255. -> None
```

But if I cut and paste the command directly from the command use line above in the same container it works fine, so I assume the error is within the subprocess environment:

```
(base) root@deabf77921e8:/ # ./bin/elkq.py --env=test --vertical=trk --index='bps-trace-*' \
 --testenv=test12 --fields=@timestamp,message,bps.application --aggs=bps.application --start=now-4h \
 --end=now --json --fany='("error")' \
 --fmust='[{"fields.buypass.com/name": "id-pro-_VERT_-*"}, {"bps.application": "*-_TESTENV_"}]'
{
  "aggregations": {
    "bps.application": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "doc_count": 15,
          "key": "id-pro-trk-trk-scim-api-test12"
        },
        {
          "doc_count": 1,
          "key": "id-pro-trk-trk-freg-gateway-test12"
        },
        {
          "doc_count": 1,
          "key": "id-pro-trk-trk-id-proofing-web-test12"
        }
      ],
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0
    }
  },
  "count": "max count found:17 rows in 0.05 sec"
}
(base) root@deabf77921e8:/ # echo $?
0
```

I know it has something to do with the --fmust parameter, because if I leave it out it works, and I earlier solved it by using a default parameter via argparse:

```
r'[{"fields.buypass.com/name": "id-pro-_VERT_-*"}, {"bps.application": "*-_TESTENV_"}]'
```

In powershell it works simply by double-quoting the `"` to `""` but the CI runs linux containers.

Any help on debugging this very appreciated, thanks

Comment: Show how you're setting `exe`. The problem is most likely because of incorrect quotes. You don't need quotes around arguments when they're list elements, that's only needed when the arguments are parsed by the shell.

Comment: @Barmar it is the command line above printing the exe list

Answer (score 0):

I changed the subprocess.check_output() to use `shell=True` on linux,
might be a dirty workaround but now it works in both powershell and bash with json parameters:

```
shell = True
if sys.platform != 'win32':
   exe = ' '.join(exe)
   shell = False
try:
    out = subprocess.check_output(exe, shell=shell)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    log.error(f"unable to execute:{exe} -> {e} -> {out}")
    return None
```